# Issues while deploying a service from Gitlab repository using startup script

Tags: git, go, google-compute-engine, startup

I am currently having issues while trying to deploy my app (currently the first service of my microservices).

I followed https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine but using my own service, hosted on gitlab.

I, however, had to edit the script since it doesn't work (sudo issue so I have to give the privileges to each of my commands):

```
set -ex

# Talk to the metadata server to get the project id and location of the application binary.
PROJECTID=$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")

# Install logging monitor. The monitor will automatically pick up logs send to
# syslog.
sudo curl -s "https://storage.googleapis.com/signals-agents/logging/google-fluentd-install.sh" | sudo bash
sudo service google-fluentd restart &

# Install dependencies from apt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -yq ca-certificates supervisor git emacs

echo "alias ne='emacs -nw'" >> .bashrc
source /.bashrc

# Creating .ssh dir
sudo mkdir -p ~/.ssh

# Generating ssh requirements
sudo ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''

# Injecting ssh key
sudo echo "ssh-rsa xxxx...... john@doe.com" > micro_service.pub
sudo mv micro_service.pub ~/.ssh/

sudo echo "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx......
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----" > micro_service
sudo mv micro_service ~/.ssh/

# Injecting conf
sudo echo "Host gitlab
    Hostname gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/micro_service
    User john@doe.com" > config
sudo mv config ~/.ssh/

# adding knows hosts
ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Get the service's source code.
git clone git@gitlab.com:PROJECT/MY-SERVICE.git service

# Create a goapp user. The application will run as this user.
sudo getent passwd goapp || sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -m -d /home/goapp goapp
sudo chown -R goapp:goapp /service

# Configure supervisor to run the Go app.
sudo echo "
[program:goapp]
directory=/service
command=/service/main argument1 argument2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=goapp
environment=HOME=\"/home/goapp\",USER=\"goapp\"
stdout_logfile=syslog
stderr_logfile=syslog
" > goapp.conf

sudo mv goapp.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/goapp.conf

sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update

# Application should now be running under supervisor
```

After all of this, it still doesn't work (now stuck on some new gitlab issues..).

Do I have the right approach? Is it really the way to go because it seems really hard when it should be way easier... (I create the instance, script gets ran. It clones the service and run it using `supervisor`).

There is the CLI I am using to create my instance:

```
gcloud compute instances create my-instance \
    --image-family=debian-9 \
    --image-project=debian-cloud \
    --machine-type=g1-small \
    --scopes userinfo-email,cloud-platform \
    --metadata-from-file startup-script=startup-script.sh \
    --zone us-central1-f \
    --tags http-server
```

Comment: If you had to use `sudo` to run `curl`, you've got other problems in your environment that are beyond the scope of that tutorial. Try following the tutorial exactly, first, before trying to apply it to your own application.

Comment: I edited my question so you can see how I create my instance